# Color manipulation for video

Tags: opencv

I am trying to convert video into either of r,g,b color. I tried the code from the link below:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html

But i am getting an error for this as:

This program shows how to write video files.
You can extract the R or G or B color channel of the input video.
Usage:

### ./video-write inputvideoName [ R | G | B] [Y | N]

[avi @ 0x9141cc0] time base not set
Could not open the output video for write: sample.avi

Can anyone help me with what is time base and how to set it in detail since I am new to it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)` doesn't return the FPS, try to replace it with a fix value i.e. `30`.

Comment: Thank you.. Next problem I am getting is that it is working properly for mkv video format but showing error-'could not open video to write' for avi format. Also the size of video after color change is too large. Can i get some efficient way for color manipulation of video

Comment: What do you mean under too large? You can try to compress it before processing.

Comment: How can i compress a video ?.. Can you please provide me a sample code for that.

Comment: I thought to a 3rdparty application i.e. [virtualdub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) or [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)